# submit a form using ajax and jquery-confirm.js

Tags: jquery, ajax

The Ajax call is working without using the alert confirmation. but when I added the alert confirmation the ajax call didn't respond and I don't know where is the problem.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<form id="add-offer">
  <input type="number" name="offer" class="form-control price_offered" value="" step="any">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Add offer   </button>
</form>
```

```js
$("#add-offer").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.alert({
    title: 'Confirmation ',
    content: ' Are you sure.... bla bla bla? ',
    rtl: true,
    closeIcon: true,
    buttons: {
      confirm: {
        text: 'Confirm ',
        btnClass: 'btn-blue',
        action: function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/add-offer.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {},
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              if (response.success == 1) {
                alert(response.message);
              } else {
                alert(response.message);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      },
      cancel: {
        text: 'Cancel ',
        action: function() {}
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue with the function block context. You can set the data variable to get the `e.target` as the Form Data parameter and try. Check the code below:

```js
$("#add-offer").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $.alert({
    title: 'Confirmation ',
    content: ' Are you sure.... bla bla bla? ',
    rtl: true,
    closeIcon: true,
    buttons: {
      confirm: {
        text: 'Confirm ',
        btnClass: 'btn-blue',
        action: function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/add-offer.php',
            data: new FormData(e.target),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {},
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              if (response.success == 1) {
                alert(response.message);
              } else {
                alert(response.message);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      },
      cancel: {
        text: 'Cancel ',
        action: function() {}
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<form id="add-offer">
  <input type="number" name="offer" class="form-control price_offered" value="" step="any">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Add offer   </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$.alert({` with `alert({`

See jsfiddle.net/msteel9999/eyk0q37d/3

Comment: The comment below your answer is part of the answer to which my review comment applies. So plaease update your answer to include the link and followup the essentials of my previous comment prevents getting your answer at the "low quality answer" section of SO review.